# Testing if a string is a palindrome using a stack

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I am attempting to take a user inputted word, ad it to a stack and then check to see if that word is a palindrome. I am attempting to pop everything off the stack and onto a new string and then compare the strings. I believe my current issue is that my pop() function doesn't actually return a value. It actually just cuts off the tail node and then reprints the string without the tail node. I guess my question is, how do I write my pop() function so that it returns the "popped" value?

Here is my main method

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     Stack_Scott_Robinson<Character> myList = new Stack_Scott_Robinson<Character>(); //create a list object
     System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
     String s = input.next();
     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        myList.push(s.charAt(i));
     }
     String reverseInput = "";
     while (!myList.isEmpty()){
        reverseInput = reverseInput + myList.Pop();
     }
     if (s.equals(reverseInput)){
        System.out.println("This is a palindrome");
     }else{
        System.out.println("This is not a palidrome");
     System.out.print("Would you like to re-run code with different input string(y/n)?");
     another = input.next();
     }
```

Here is my pop() method

```
public void Pop()
{
  Node countList = end; //set "count" node at the front of the list
  int size = 0; //initialize the size variable
  //moves the count node down the list and increments the size variable
  while (countList != null)
  {
     countList = countList.next;
     size++;
  }
  if (size == 0){ //empty list
     System.out.println("error: empty list");
  }else if (size == 1) //one node list
  {
     top = null;
     end = null;
     System.out.println("list is now empty");
  }
  else{
     Node current = end;//set a current node at the front of the list
     for (int i = 0; i<size-2; i++)//-2 because the list starts at 0 and we want the second to last position
     {
        current = current.next;//moves the current node down the list until it is 
     } 
     Node temporary = current.next;  //the second to last position
     Node temp = top;//create a new node space
     top = current;//set the new node equal to the second to last position
     top.next = null;//sets the node as the tail
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how java.util.Vector does it (java.util.Stack extends Vector)

```
public synchronized E pop() {
    E       obj;
    int     len = size();

    obj = peek();
    removeElementAt(len - 1);

    return obj;
}
```

and

```
public synchronized void removeElementAt(int index) {
    if (index >= elementCount) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index + " >= " +
                                                 elementCount);
    }
    else if (index < 0) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    int j = elementCount - index - 1;
    if (j > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index + 1, elementData, index, j);
    }
    modCount++;
    elementCount--;
    elementData[elementCount] = null; /* to let gc do its work */
}
```

In the pop method, you can see that we know what object to remove because they get it using peek(); Then they just remove the element at the end of the vector. Hopefully this helps. I'm not sure how you are representing your Stack under the hood, so I can't really give you a better answer without that.